# Which Platformer with characters stacking on one another is found in this Jimquisition Video?

Tags: game-identification

I was watching semi watching the *Game Journalism Of Thrones* episode of The Jimquisition on Jim Sterling's Channel when I saw this platformer where it seems the characters are stacked onto of one another.

[image: Unknown Platformer]

It first appears at [13:06 Seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxdfWn4Sbnc&t=13m6s)

A reverse image search on Google wasn't very helpful

[image: "PC game" - Thank you Captain Obvious!]

I would like to know what game this is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long time scrolling through the comments on that video, I finally found the answer.

It is [Lapis x Labyrinth](https://nisamerica.com/games/lapis-labyrinth/) for the Nintendo Switch. It is made by Nippon Ichi Software, Inc. and releases tomorrow, May 28 2019 (May 31 2019 in the EU).

Here's a trailer for it:

Since you're already on Jim's channel, here's his review of the game:

Comment: *"Releases tomorrow"* - so Jim *does* get some pre-release games!

Answer (score 6):

The game is called [Lapis x Labyrinth](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/lapis-x-labyrinth-switch/).

While I linked the switch page, it is also available for PS4

I've found it by pausing the video on a frame with two enemies defeated messages, and googled both of them ("Hammer knight" "Killer bee")